# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified that I can't solve

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have tried all the helps available online and still cannot resolve this with my code. I have tried everything. please review my code and find out what is wrong. Thank you in advance.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCanceling" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowDeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" width="680px" style="line-height: 180%;" DataKeyNames="NoteId" autogeneratecolumns="False"
                     emptydatatext="No notes." showfooter="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"  CssClass="mGrid" CellPadding="14" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"   >
                <headerstyle backcolor="#5D7B9D" forecolor="MediumBlue"/>                    
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <footerstyle backcolor="#5D7B9D" forecolor="White" Font-Bold="True"/>                        
              <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775"></AlternatingRowStyle>

                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NoteId" DataField="NoteId" ReadOnly="true" visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField>

                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" Runat="server" CommandName="Update">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>  
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this note?');" CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="Name" >
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:label ID="linktextbox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>'></asp:label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="linklabel3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="135px" HeaderText="Date" >
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:label ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NoteDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:tt}")%>'></asp:label>

                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>

                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NoteDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:tt}")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="360px" HeaderText="Note" >


                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" style="border:1px solid black;" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="350px" height="34px" Text='<%# Eval("Note")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>

                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>

                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Note")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                    <RowStyle ForeColor="#333333" BackColor="#F7F6F3" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />                        
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />                    
                </asp:GridView>



   <asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AssignConnectionString %>" deletecommand="deleteNote" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="updateNote" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">                   
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

code behind:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim Note2 As TextBox = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox)

    Dim conStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("assignConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection(conStr)
    cn.Open()
    Dim updCmd As New SqlCommand("updateNote", cn)
    updCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    updCmd.Parameters.Add("@NoteId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Text
    updCmd.Parameters.Add("@Note", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Note2.Text

    SqlDataSource1.DataBind()
    updCmd.Parameters.Clear()
    bindGridView()
End Sub
```

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateNote]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here


@NoteId int,
@Note varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
Update Notes Set Note = @Note Where NoteId = @NoteId
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Not Sure, but try nvarchar instead of varchar in this line

```
updCmd.Parameters.Add("@Note", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Note2.Text
```

it will like

```
updCmd.Parameters.Add("@Note", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Note2.Text
```

your edited code behind :

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
Dim Note2 As TextBox = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox)

Dim conStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("assignConnectionString").ConnectionString
Dim cn As New SqlConnection(conStr)
cn.Open()
Dim updCmd As New SqlCommand("updateNote", cn)
updCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
updCmd.Parameters.Add("@NoteId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Text
updCmd.Parameters.Add("@Note", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Note2.Text

SqlDataSource1.DataBind()
updCmd.Parameters.Clear()
bindGridView()
End Sub
```

Comment: is there anything else? changing to NVarchar did not work. In the database, the field is actually varchar(max). not sure why i put nvarchar(50) on the stored proc

Answer (score 0):

Check the datatype in your code below :

```
 updCmd.Parameters.Add("@Note", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Note2.Text
```

Check you datatype in StoredProcedure

```
@Note nvarchar(50)
```

use `nvarchar` at both ends

Comment: the actual database has varchar(max), so I changed my sp to that, and left the codebehind at varchar. still no luck. I tried nvarchar in codebehind and it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing all of the fields in my gridview to "Eval" instead of "Bind", except for the field I wanted to update. Which was exact opposite of other solutions, where they said to change all to Bind, except the field you want to use. my gridview below is how I did it:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCanceling" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowDeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" width="680px" style="line-height: 180%;" autogeneratecolumns="False"
                DataKeyNames="NoteId" emptydatatext="No notes." showfooter="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"  CssClass="mGrid" CellPadding="14" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"   >
            <headerstyle backcolor="#5D7B9D" forecolor="MediumBlue"/>                    
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <footerstyle backcolor="#5D7B9D" forecolor="White" Font-Bold="True"/>                        
          <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775"></AlternatingRowStyle>

                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NoteId" DataField="NoteId" ReadOnly="true" visible="False" />
                        <asp:TemplateField>                            
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" Runat="server" CommandName="Update">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>  
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this note?');" CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="Name" >
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:label ID="linktextbox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="linklabel3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="135px" HeaderText="Date" >
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:label ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NoteDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:tt}")%>'></asp:label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>                                
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NoteDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:tt}")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="360px" HeaderText="Note" >
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" style="border:1px solid black;" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="350px" height="34px" Text='<%# Bind("Note")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>                               
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Note")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                    <RowStyle ForeColor="#333333" BackColor="#F7F6F3" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />                        
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />                    
                </asp:GridView>
```

Plus I had to add an update parameter to the sqldatasource as below just for the textbox that i was updating:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AssignConnectionString %>" deletecommand="deleteNote" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="updateNote" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">                   
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Note" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```